# Change the "Sort By" option of a category with code

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, category-products

I want to change the `Sort By` (Default product sort order in the front end) option that is available in the `Catalog -> Manage Categories -> Display Settings`  with a php script. I want to set that to `position` for all categories.

Is there a way to do that in both Magento 1 and 2 ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Found the answer for magento 2. `$category->setDefaultSortBy('position'); $category->save();`

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do change setting from System Configuration.

Magento has a system configuration field where you can set `Default product sort order` Position for all Category.

For magento2,Please go to admin `Store>Configuration>Catalog>Catalog>StoreFrontend` And Select your desire default sorting field from their and Save the configuration.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. If I do this, will I be able to check that "Use config value" checkbox through code?

Comment: NO need. Check `"Use config value" checkbox through code`